# Inverse linear transformation

Tags: c#, c, square

I am implementing a square encryption algorithm, but maybe someone knows a way to inverse linear transformation. I take the input bytes of 16 bytes and put them row by row into a two-dimensional matrix input_state[4,4] doing a linear transformation by the following C# code.

```
private byte[,] LinerPreob(byte[,] input_state)
    {
        byte[,] coef = new byte[4, 4]{
            { 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x03 },
            { 0x03, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01 },
            { 0x01, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01 },
            { 0x01, 0x01, 0x03, 0x02 }
        };
        byte[,] result = new byte[4, 4];
        byte temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
            {
                temp = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                    temp ^= Mult(input_state[i, k], coef[k, j]);
                result[i, j] = temp;
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Transformation over each byte in the matrix according to the formula temp^=multiplication in the Galois field (256) (function Mult) of the current byte by the coefficient in the coef matrix. ^ is an XOR operation.

Comment: Better to do in Matlab.  You can create a dll in Matlab and then call from c# application.

Comment: everything must be done in the program

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: this C# but C too good

Comment: i figured out how to do inverse linear transformation in square encryption

Comment: you need to enter the coefficients in the decimal number system, there is an inverse matrix, see the American site iacr

Comment: My encryption Square - https://github.com/mikl43/Square-encryption